# Loop through all Resources in ResourceManager - C#

Tags: c#, resources

How do I loop into all the resources in the resourcemanager?

Ie:
foreach (string resource in ResourceManager)
  //Do something with the recource.

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use ResourceManager.[GetResourceSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset.aspx)() for a list of all resources for a given culture. The returned ResourceSet implements IEnumerable (you can use foreach).

---

To answer Nico's question: you can count the elements of an `IEnumerable` by casting it to the generic `IEnumerable<object>` and use the [`Enumerable.Count<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx) extension method, which is new in C# 3.5:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(..);
var count = resSet.Cast<object>().Count();
```

Comment: how the hell do I get a count for it?

Comment: @Nico: IEnumerable's don't implement a Count property but you can iterate the entries and count them. Alternatively you can cast the RessourceSet to IEnumerable<object> and use the Count() extension method which is new in C# 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to loop through all available cultures? I am trying to write a T4 template that generates localization json files from resx files.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why would you like to loop through all of the resources.

Anyway, `ResourceManager` needs to be instantiated giving it a `Type` or the base name where to lookup for resources. Then you will be able to retrieve a `ResourceSet` but for a given `CultureInfo`, ergo if you want to obtain all the resources for a given `ResourceManager

Comment: We have a use for it where we allow a client admin to override language literals in the DB so we need a page to show all the resources they can override.