# What is the preferred method of storing data local to a web application that does not change frequently?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, linq-to-xml

I have a custom ASP.NET 4 web application that is currently running on Windows Azure.  There is a large set of data (several thousand entries, each with a "key" value and a 1-3 sentence description) that changes very infrequently (twice in the last 25 years) that I need to be able to display as part of the application (in drop-down controls, grids, etc).

I'm thinking it doesn't make sense to store the data in a database since it will hardly ever need to be changed, and would be shipping several sentences over on each page reload.  I am evaluating both an XML file accessed via LINQ-to-XML or a Resource file.  There is the potential need for the strings to be localized (which I think would steer towards resource files), but because of the business logic involved, I will need to sometimes query on the data as well based on various attributes (specific "key" value or other attributes, I believe would be easier with LINQ).

Does anybody have any thoughts on what to use here?  There may be other options as well, I'd certainly entertain those also... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't rule out a database just because the data isn't changing - assuming Azure allows it, a lightweight database like SQL CE or SQLite would probably work just fine.

That said, the other factors you mentioned (mapping from a key to a short string, potential for localization, displayed as part of the UI) makes a resource file seem like the best way to go.

Running queries based on the resource strings seems a bit odd, however - I believe it's possible (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140043/loop-through-all-resources-in-resourcemanager-c)), but running any sort of query like "give me all resource strings containing 'foo'" would break the moment you localized anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a Windows Azure table. It's fast and reliable and partially supports LINQ. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135725.aspx) are query operators available for LINQ on Azure. Also if you need localization then you might use the same table and the culture as PartitionKey. Also you won't have problems when scaling up or down, because the storage will be common to all nodes.

An option to the Windows Azure table might be a dedicated container with an XML file accessed via LINQ-to-XML. But I would prefer the first variant.

Comment: Given that the data is unlikely to change, why would you prefer an Azure table?  It would seem that the cost would be higher and the access speed would be slower than a file on local disk, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Why not store XML file in the resource?  This will allow you to have benefits of both: simple packaging, quick access, LINQ, and localization.

However, I would not rule out SQL Azure, if you already have a database hosted there.  Access to it is quick and you will not be paying any extra charges (provided you already have database deployed), no matter how often you connect to it.  ATS is slightly slower (albeit way more scalable) but it'll cost you a fraction of a penny anytime you go to ATS for pretty much anything.

Overall, there is a dozen ways to do this and all of them will be OK. If performance is your number one concern, embedding it into the application via resource is likely to be the best approach.  If flexibility & deployment are your biggest concerns, SQL Azure is likely the best approach.