# asp.net Get all Resources from .resx Without Specifying Culture (ResourceManager.GetResourceSet )

Tags: asp.net, resources, resx, cultureinfo, resourcemanager

I first came across a question similar to mine here at stack overflow: [Loop through all Resources in ResourceManager - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140043/loop-through-all-resources-in-resourcemanager-c). It only solved part of what I need to do. When you request an entry in a resource file for a specific culture, if there is not one present it will default back on the neutral culture resource file.

I need to loop through each entry for a given resource file and GetResourceSet requires a culture. For example I have a neutral resource file with 3 entries in it and a culture specific resource file accompanying the neutral file with 1 entry.

My neutral resource example file is MyResource.resx and my culture specific resource example file is MyResource.en-gb.resx. The following code shows how I am currently trying to loop through and access all of the resource entries.

```
Dim cultInfo as New CultureInfo(culture)
For Each entry As System.Collections.DictionaryEntry In myResourceManager.GetResourceSet(cultInfo, True, True)

Next
```

**Neutral Resource File Entries**

- FullName / Full Name
- PhoneNumber / Phone Number
- State / State

**Culture Specific Resource File Entry**

- State / County

When I call GetResourceSet for the specific culture I only get back 1 entry. I was expecting (and want) to get back all 3 entries with the one culture specific entry overridden. Here is what I want returned:

- FullName / Full Name
- PhoneNumber / Phone Number
- State / **County**

Is there anyway that I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The GetString method of a ResourceManager object properly handles the traversing of resource files to locate the correct Value for a given key based on a culture. The base/neutral/default resource file can be obtained using the [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx), which gives you all the possible keys for the resource file (assuming you setup your resource files this way).

Looping on the DictionaryEntry objects found in the GetResourceSet method of a ResourceManager, based on the Invariant Culture and then calling GetString for each Key using the specific culture passed in, you will get the correct Value for a given key based on the culture.

```
For Each entry As DictionaryEntry In myResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, True, True)
     Dim strKey as String = entry.Key.ToString()
     Dim strValue as String = myResourceManager.GetString(entry.Key.ToString(), cultInfo)
Next
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand this *workaround* solves the issue, but still the behaviour you found (and I found as well) for this `GetResourceSet` method does not reflect what's in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Well, actually I tried it and in my case it does not solve the problem. When iterating over the resourceSet, I only get the locale-specific keys. The set has no key from the fallback resource at all. :( And I double-checked I'm passing the correct culture, true, true.

Comment: In the end, I managed it like so: I created a dictionary out of `InvariantCulture`, and another one out of `CurrentUICulture`, then I merged the latter over former.