# Get all resources in array

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a VB.NET program with lots of embedded resources which are images. Is there a way to get all the resources in an array so I can acces them in a for loop?

I currently have to do it this way:

```
 images(1) = My.Resources.image1
 images(2) = My.Resources.image2
 '...
 images(80) = My.Resources.image80
```

Comment: This should help:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140043/loop-through-all-resources-in-resourcemanager-c][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140043/loop-through-all-resources-in-resourcemanager-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
Dim ResourceSet As Resources.ResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
For Each Dict As DictionaryEntry In ResourceSet.OfType(Of Object)()
    If TypeOf (Dict.Value) Is Drawing.Image Then
        Debug.WriteLine(Dict.Key) 'outputting resource name
       (Do stuff here)
    End If
Next
```

It appears that the key is the name of the resource.

Comment: it says: System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Comment: Sorry, edited above after actually testing it.  There has to be a better way than that OfType(of Object) but I can't seem to see it.  Also, I had to change the parameters in the GetResourceSet based on the application I tested this in... so you may need to adjust those.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset%28v=VS.80%29.aspx