# How to add all pictures in resources to an array in VB?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, image

I'm new to VB and programming in general. I'm having some trouble trying to add all the pictures I have from Resources into an image array, I think it can be done with a loop, but I don't know how... Sorry for asking such a simple question and thanks!

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912078/get-all-resources-in-array) is a similar question of yours that can also be found here in SO. I have edited the code there so that you can add the images into an list/array.

```
Dim ResourceSet As Resources.ResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
Dim lstImage As New List(Of Image) 'You can use array here, but I prefered list.

For Each Dict As DictionaryEntry In ResourceSet.OfType(Of Object)()
    If TypeOf (Dict.Value) Is Drawing.Image Then
          lstImage.Add(Dict.Value)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I dind't find out that answer before, but it's exactly what I needed